# JailBreak iOS: adding custom view to input call view

Tags: ios, theos, tweak

I need to add my custom view to input call view. I have got jail broken device with iOS 9.3.2. I've installed Theos to my MacBook. I've installed mobile substrate to iOS. And now I don't know what I need to do.
I found that I have to modify InCallService.app. But I cannot find needed class for tweak.
Also I don't understand how can I write logs. I tried to use NSLog(@"aaa") and %log(@"aaa") but I cannot find file with logs.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to add something to the app, modifying the .app isn't the easiest way. If you have MobileSubstrate installed you can hook a method from the Phone application and using basic iOS paradigms like MVC you can find the views you need to modify and go from there. If you need the header files you can either dump them yourself with class-dump-z or see if [these](https://github.com/MohammadAG/iOS-Unpopular-Headers/tree/master/InCallService) are still valid.

Logging data is also quite easy with Ryan Petrich's [deviceconsole](https://github.com/rpetrich/deviceconsole)

Just run the command `deviceconsole --process < YOUR HOOKED PROCESSES' NAME >` in your console after installing `deviceconsole` onto your Mac, and anything in your code using `%log();` will show up in the console.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I have installed mobile substrate and the main problem was the finding view controller for incoming call. Tonight I managed to get logs from my device and I found required view controller.

Comment: That's awesome! Good luck.

Comment: By the way. Maybe this comment will help another beginners in the JB development.   
1. For getting logs I use jurpleConsole.   
2. You can get commands for Theos' xm files there [Theos info](http://iphonedevwiki.net/index.php/Logos)

Comment: Also you can find info about getting log by this [link: https://www.theiphonewiki.com/wiki/System_Log](https://www.theiphonewiki.com/wiki/System_Log)